# UTF-8 raw character? to normal string

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, utf-8

I want to decode utf-8(or unicode) text to normal string.

for example, I want to convert "\uc778\uc0b0\uc544\uc5f0\uc2dc\uba58\ud2b8, \uce58\uba74\uc5f4\uad6c\uc804\uc0c9\uc81c" kind of string to readable text.

I struggled with system.text.utf8encoding text.encoding.utf8.getstring() but it's not working...

How can I solve the problem? It seems that the solution would be simple...
If possible, it would be great if you write the code in VB.Net

Thank you for your advice!

---

Thanks for replying.

I think I didn't write my point clearly.

The question is that I want to convert "\uc885\ud569\uc9c4\ub8cc\uc2e4 \uacac\ud559 / \uce58\uacfc\uc758\uc0ac\uc724\ub9ac \ud1a0\ub860" (unicode 'code', not 'chracter') to a readable string, for example, "가나다라". or chinese or whatever.

and, I need the .NET code to do that.

tried

```
theString = Convert.toString("\uc885\ud569");
```

tried

```
Dim utf8Encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
Dim encodedString() As Byte
encodedString = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(encodedString) .....
```

and a few more, but nothing converts "\uc885\ud569" to "가나". (that's an example. I got that each '\u????' code matches a single character, for ex '가')

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, it's not working? What does the code do? Could you actually show us your code?

Comment: Also, [tags don't belong to the question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/130186).

Comment: I wrote my question again. Could you give me some more help? @svick

Comment: Like @scartag said, you don't need to convert anything. `"\uc885\ud569"` already is exactly what you want. If you can't write that to console, it's a problem with the console, not with the string.

Comment: @svick I mean, I want readable text. '"\uc885\ud569"' cannot be read by person, but "가나" can be. I want a converter that converts '"\uc885\ud569"' (this is also a text, but not readable) to '"가나"'. I'm sorry if I am still missing the point.

Comment: @svick I found the right term "unescape"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understand what the problem is. A string like `"\uc778\uc0b0"` is exactly the same as `"인산"` **in C#** (and it's UTF-16, not UTF-8). But VB.NET doesn't understand such escape sequences.

I think the best option here would be to write the Koren characters directly, something like `"인산"` is valid VB.NET code.

If you really need to use C#-like escape sequences, [you can use `Regex.Unescape()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5095260/41071):

```
Dim escaped = "\uc778\uc0b0\uc544\uc5f0\uc2dc\uba58\ud2b8, \uce58\uba74\uc5f4\uad6c\uc804\uc0c9\uc81c"
Dim unescaped = Regex.Unescape(escaped)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything to convert it.

The text is in chinese characters (or similar asian characters)

Simply output it i guess. worked for me.

I simply did a `Console.WriteLine()` from linqpad.

Each of the \uXXXX is a unicode value for a specific character.

Comment: thanks but I want to get the character into a variable. but console. command does not support that feature. is there any other code to convert it? thanks! @svick

Comment: @klados That's most likely because your console font doesn't support these characters.